# Server Request Interrupted Heroku

Tags: javascript, django, react-native, heroku

I am using React Native and Django. Everything was working fine, until I made a request and I got the following error:

`sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/api/obtain-img" host=notarealapp.herokuapp.com request_id=... fwd="..." dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=503 bytes=316 protocol=https`

Also, I don't know if this is useful information, but I got the following error too:

`<rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/api/obtain-img'>`

The fetch code I used is this:

```
let token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("token");
console.log(uri);
let filename = uri.split("/").pop();

let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", { uri: uri, name: filename, type: type });
// formData.append("cateogry", category);
// formData.append("mission", value);
console.log(formData);
return await fetch("https://notarealapp.herokuapp.com/api/obtain-img", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    Authorization: `JWT ${JSON.parse(token)}`,
  },
  body: formData,
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

And my Django code is the following:

```
class ObtainImageUri(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request)
        return Response({"succes": "The receipt was stored successfully."}, status=200)
```

I am open to any help.

Thank you

Comment: You are trying to make a `GET` request or `POST` request?

Comment: A POST request.